# How To Filter In Mongoose from Rest API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

So, I'm using Express to create an API. On this API, I want to get a list of customers from MongoDB using Mongoose. I have the following route (for my question, ignore my paging and limits).

```js
routes.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const page = req.query.page;
  let limit = req.query.limit;

  const match = GetCustomerFilters(req);

  if (limit && limit > 100) {
    limit = 25;
  }

  const results = await GetCustomers({ page, limit, match });

  res.status(200).json({
    status: "ok",
    data: {
      currentPage: results.currentPage,
      totalPages: results.totalPages,
      limit: results.limit,
      count: results.data.length,
      total: results.count,
      results: results.data,
    },
  });
});
```

To make this complete, I will show you what `GetCustomerFilters` function looks like first, which creates the filter query based on the passed in req variable from the route. Just note that these are in different files but I'm putting them all here for you to see.

```js
const GetCustomerFilters = (req) => {
  const match = {};

  const filterActive = req.query.active;

  const filterCreated = req.query.created;
  const filterCreated_lt = req.query.created_lt;
  const filterCreated_gt = req.query.created_gt;
  const filterCreated_lte = req.query.created_lte;
  const filterCreated_gte = req.query.created_gte;

  if (filterActive != undefined) {
    match.active = filterActive.toLowerCase() === "true";
  }

  if (filterCreated) {
    match.createdAt = Date.parse(filterCreated);
  } else {
    let matchCreatedAt = {};

    if (filterCreated_lt) {
      matchCreatedAt = { ...matchCreatedAt, $lt: Date.parse(filterCreated_lt) };
    }

    if (filterCreated_gt) {
      matchCreatedAt = { ...matchCreatedAt, $gt: Date.parse(filterCreated_gt) };
    }

    if (filterCreated_lte) {
      matchCreatedAt = {
        ...matchCreatedAt,
        $lte: Date.parse(filterCreated_lte),
      };
    }

    if (filterCreated_gte) {
      matchCreatedAt = {
        ...matchCreatedAt,
        $gte: Date.parse(filterCreated_gte),
      };
    }

    if (
      !(
        Object.keys(matchCreatedAt).length === 0 &&
        matchCreatedAt.constructor === Object
      )
    ) {
      match.createdAt = matchCreatedAt;
    }
  }

  return match;
};
```

And finally, to complete the first code block, I have the `GetCustomers` function.

```js
const GetCustomers = async ({ page = 1, limit = 25, match }) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    page = Number.parseInt(page) - 1;
    limit = Number.parseInt(limit);

    const total = await CustomerModel.countDocuments();

    const totalPages = Math.ceil(total / limit);

    return CustomerModel.find({ ...match })
      .limit(limit)
      .skip(limit * page)
      .then((results) => {
        resolve({
          currentPage: page + 1,
          totalPages,
          limit,
          count: total,
          data: results,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

My question is, can this be made better. My first concern (you can see in the second block of code) is all the code I have for different ways to filter when the Customer was created. It can be matched exactly, before a certain date, after a certain date, before or equal to a certain date, and after or equal to a certain date. My first thought it to abstract that to a separate function where the same function is used for any date and I would pass in the database field and the actual query parameters. Would there be a different/better way? Maybe using the function below

```js
const FilterDate = (fieldExact, fieldLT, fieldGT, fieldLTE, fieldGTE) => {
  let results = null;

  if (fieldExact) {
    results = Date.parse(fieldExact);
  } else {
    results = {};

    if (fieldLT) {
      results  = { ...results, $lt: Date.parse(fieldLT) };
    }

    if (fieldGT) {
      results = { ...results, $gt: Date.parse(fieldGT) };
    }

    if (fieldLTE) {
      results = {
        ...results,
        $lte: Date.parse(fieldLTE),
      };
    }

    if (fieldGTE) {
      results = {
        ...results,
        $gte: Date.parse(fieldGTE),
      };
    }
  }
  
  return results;
}
```

And then adding it to the match by using:

```js
let createdAtFilter = FilterDate(req.query.created, req.query.created_lt,
req.query.created_gt, req.query.created_lte, req.query.created_gte);

if (
!(Object.keys(createdAtFilter).length === 0 && createdAtFilter.constructor === Object)
) {
  match.createdAt = createdAtFilter;
}
```

That way, if I have a `updatedAt` field, I don't have to perform all those checks again and can reuse the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see room for a couple improvements. First, assuming that the query from the caller's side is not open to change, consider directly associating the caller's API comparison operators to Mongo's. With that, we can shrink the creation part of your filtering code to a nice, declarative `reduce()`, like this:

```js
const ops = {
  created: '$eq',
  created_lt: '$lt',
  created_gt: '$gt',
  created_lte: '$lte',
  created_gte: '$gte'
};

function GetCustomerFilters(req) {
  const query = req.query;
  const comparators = Object.entries(query).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (ops[key]) acc[ops[key]] = Date.parse(value);
    return acc;
  }, {});
  let filters = { createdAt: comparators };
  filters.active = req.query.active === 'true';
  return filters; 
}

const exampleRequest = {
  query: {
    active: 'true',
    created_gte: '07/04/2020',
    created_lt: '07/09/2020'
  }
};

console.log(GetCustomerFilters(exampleRequest));
```

Another improvement that should be made to the code regards the wrapping of the `find()` in a promise constructor. `find()` returns a promise, which is made plain by your use of `.then()` on the call chain, so there's no need to wrap that promise in another.  In other words, improve it like this:

```
const GetCustomers = async ({ page = 1, limit = 25, match }) => {
  page = Number.parseInt(page) - 1;
  limit = Number.parseInt(limit);

  const total = await CustomerModel.countDocuments();
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(total / limit);

  return CustomerModel.find({ ...match })
    .limit(limit)
    .skip(limit * page)
    .then(results => {
      return {
        currentPage: page + 1,
        totalPages,
        limit,
        count: total,
        data: results,
      };
    })
};
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. Also, just to note, in my case I can control the query from the client's side as I will be designing the client-side based on the API. I plan to use GraphQL (once I learn it) but want to offer myself a RestAPI with good design practices going forward. I will accept and award bounty once StackOverflow allows me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be to separate the **date** from the **range**, meaning that you should supply your query creation function with 2 params, one for the date being queried (createdAt in this case), and another that specify the *range* to search for, like equal, gt, lt, etc. this second argument would be supplied from the front-end, possibly by presenting the user with a pre-defined list of options to choose from.
An example would be something like this:

```
function createFilter(date, range) {//range here will be a string one of ['gt','gte','lt','lte'] or nothing - which means exact match.  
   
  date = Date.parse(date);
   
    let match =  range ? {['$'+range]:date} : date;
    return {createdAt: match}
};
```

This way, if you need in the future to use the same query patterns on a different field, all you'll need to do is to add another argument `field_name` and updated the returned query object to `{[field_name]:match}`

Comment: Thank you! I will look at incorporating this into my logic and this gives me something to go off of.